# Charset encoding problem

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an Arabic web site. However, I use AJAX to save some text in my data base. The AJAX works fine with me. My problem is, when I save the data in my database and try to print it on my screen, it returns a weird text. I have used the PHP function mb_detect_encoding to determine how the database deals with the text. The function returned UTF-8.
So I used iconv("windows-1256","UTF-8",$row["text"]) to print the text on the screen, but it still returning this weird thing. Please give a hand
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/288773) thread (and use the search before posting a question first).

in your case, i think you've forgotten to set the chorrect charset for you database-connection (using a `SET NAMES` statement or [mysql_set_charset()](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-set-charset.php)) - but thats hard to say.

this is a quote from [chazomaticus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30497/chazomaticus), who has given a perfect answer in the liked thread, listing all the points you have to care of:

> Storage:
>
> - Specify `utf8_unicode_ci` (or
>     equivalent) collation on all tables
>     and text columns in your database. 
>     This makes MySQL physically store and
>     retrieve values natively in UTF-8.
>
> Retrieval:
>
> - In PHP, in whatever DB wrapper you
>     use, you'll need to set the connection
>     charset to utf8.  This way, MySQL does
>     no conversion from its native UTF-8
>     when it hands data off to PHP.
>     *
>     Note that if you don't use a DB
>     wrapper, you'll probably have to issue
>     a query to tell MySQL to give you
>     results in UTF-8: `SET NAMES 'utf8'`
>     (as soon as you connect).
>
> Delivery:
>
> - You've got to tell PHP to deliver
>     the proper headers to the client, so
>     text will be interpreted as UTF-8.  In
>     PHP, you can use the `default_charset`
>     php.ini option, or manually issue the
>     `Content-Type` header yourself, which
>     is just more work but has the same
>     effect.
>
> Submission:
>
> - You want all data sent to you by
>     browsers to be in UTF-8. 
>     Unfortunately, the only way to
>     reliably do this is add the
>     `accept-charset` attribute to all your
>     `<form>` tags: `<form ...
>     accept-charset="UTF-8">`.
> - Note
>     that the W3C HTML spec says that
>     clients "should" default to sending
>     forms back to the server in whatever
>     charset the server served, but this is
>     apparently only a recommendation,
>     hence the need for being explicit on
>     every single `<form>` tag.
> - Although, on that front, you'll still
>     want to verify every submitted string
>     as being valid UTF-8 before you try to
>     store it or use it anywhere.  PHP's
>     `mb_check_encoding()` does the trick,
>     but you have to use it religiously.
>
> Processing:
>
> - This is, unfortunately, the hard
>     part.  You need to make sure that
>     every time you process a UTF-8 string,
>     you do so safely.  Easiest way to do
>     this is by making extensive use of
>     PHP's `mbstring` extension.
> - PHP's
>     string operations are NOT by default
>     UTF-8 safe.  There are some things you
>     can safely do with normal PHP string
>     operations (like concatenation), but
>     for most things you should use the
>     equivalent `mbstring` function.
> - To
>     know what you're doing (read: not mess
>     it up), you really need to know UTF-8
>     and how it works on the lowest
>     possible level.  Check out any of the
>     links from [utf8.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/288773) for some good
>     resources to learn everything you need
>     to know.
> - Also, I feel like this
>     should be said somewhere, even though
>     it may seem obvious: every PHP or HTML
>     file you'll be serving should be
>     encoded in valid UTF-8.

note that you don't need to use utf-8 - the important part is to use **the same charset everywhere**, independent of what charset that might be. but if you need to change things anyway, use utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing your web pages to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should use the same encoding (UTF-8?) in your webpages, database, *and JavaScript/AJAX*. Many people forget to set charset for AJAX requests/responses, which gives you mangled data in some browsers (*cough cough*).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your support, and sorry oezi for that confusion. I really made a search and didn't find my answer. However, it works fine with me now. I am going to explain what I did to make it work, so anybody else can get benefit of it:
- I made my tables charset to utf8_unicode_ci.
- To submit the data, I used AJAX with the default charset UTF-8.
- When I get the data from my DB, I used the iconv function as the follwoing
 iconv("UTF-8","windows-1256",$row["text"]) , and it works 
I hope that clear