# Java PreparedStatement setString changes characters

Tags: java, prepared-statement

As in title: to be sure, I was debugging my application, and so in line, where I put strings into PreparedStatement variable, special characters are changing to "?". I actually don't know where to search for things that should repair it, so I don't know if code is required.. Anyway, I'll put some here:

```
PreparedStatement stm = null;
String sql = "";

    try{
      sql = "INSERT INTO methods (name, description) VALUES (?, ?)";
      stm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
      stm.setString(1, method.getName());
      stm.setString(2, method.getDescription());
      //...
    }catch(Exception e){}
```

while debugging 'name' field was correct in method object, but after adding it into stm variable, it changed it's characters to '?'.

I have found one topic about the similar sitoatuin on SO, but there wasn't any answer that could help me since I exactely know that there is something not right in adding string to statement, not in database. But I don't know what..

Any sugestions?

PS. I'm using netbeans 6.7.1 version

EDIT: I was debugging with standard netbeans debugger, and was checking state of variables before adding strings to 'stm' variable. I was even changing getName() method to static string with special characters. So for sure everything is ok with Method class.

EDIT2: I've made one more test. Checked stm variable and one of it's properties is "charEncoding" which is set to "cp1252". So the main question is.. how to change that?

Comment: How were you checking this?  What tool did you use to verify the data in the database?

Comment: Are you saying that the return value of `method.getName()` changed after it has been called?

Comment: *Never* do `catch(Exception e){}` - if an exception happens, you'll not know that it did and what went wrong. At the very least print the stack trace: `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: Having the same issue but not fixed yet.. i am using Mysql Workbench 5.2 and Java 7. Kindly help me to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a character encoding issue to me. Perhaps the driver is transcoding your strings into the appropriate encoding for the field/table/schema/database rather than letting the server do it? If you are trying to store a character which has no representation in the encoding of the field/table/schema/database, that would explain the '?' characters.

Answer (score 3):

this normally happens by [using different charsets](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) in different locations. sound like you're getting your input as UTF-8, converting it to another chatset (maybe your database is set to something else) which breaks the special character.

to fix this: use the same charset *everywhere**. (i would recommend using UTF-8)

*take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) or [my answer to another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277365/charset-encoding-problem/4277410#4277410) (that's about a problem in php, but in java it's almost the same)

Comment: But the strings aren't going through DB. They are taken from one variable into another one in other file (java class).. JDBC driver changes charset in PreparedStatement variable?

Comment: See my answer below. It's possible that the JDBC driver is transcoding the String from Java's UTF-8 into the appropriate encoding for the database prior to sending it to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using **Oracle**? I have had similar situations, if the environment variables regarding character sets weren't defined correctly.

By default, an Oracle connection is ASCII (7-bit characters, A-Z, a-z, numbers, punctuation, ...). If you use any character outside of that (e.g. European accents, Chinese characters, ..) then you need to use something other than ASCII. UTF-8 is best. If you don't, your characters will get replaced by "?".

You'd need to get your sysadmin to set this up for you. Alternatively take a look here:

http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2009/02/what-is-nlslang-environmental-variable.html

Answer (score 0):

I do this :

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
List varBind       = new ArrayList();
String strSQL ="INSERT INTO table..... ";
varBind.add(claveEPO); //1
varBind.add(cg_num_distribuidor); //2
varBind.add(numero_docto); //3

// it's importan to do this
byte ptextRazon[] = cgRazonSocialEpo.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String razonSocial = new String(ptextRazon, "UTF-8");
varBind.add(razonSocial);//26

ps = con.queryPrecompilado(strSQL.toString(), varBind);
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
```